# Ruby CSV BOM|UTF-8 encoding for StringIO

Tags: ruby, csv, utf-8, byte-order-mark, ruby-csv

Ruby 2.6.3.

I have been trying to parse a `StringIO` object into a `CSV` instance with the `bom|utf-8` encoding, so that the BOM character (undesired) is stripped and the content is encoded to UTF-8:

```
require 'csv'

CSV_READ_OPTIONS = { headers: true, encoding: 'bom|utf-8' }.freeze

content = StringIO.new("\xEF\xBB\xBFid\n123")
first_row = CSV.parse(content, CSV_READ_OPTIONS).first

first_row.headers.first.include?("\xEF\xBB\xBF")     # This returns true
```

Apparently the `bom|utf-8` encoding does not work for `StringIO` objects, but I found that it does work for files, for instance:

```
require 'csv'

CSV_READ_OPTIONS = { headers: true, encoding: 'bom|utf-8' }.freeze

# File content is: "\xEF\xBB\xBFid\n12"
first_row = CSV.read('bom_content.csv', CSV_READ_OPTIONS).first

first_row.headers.first.include?("\xEF\xBB\xBF")     # This returns false
```

Considering that I need to work with `StringIO` directly, why does `CSV` ignores the `bom|utf-8` encoding? Is there any way to remove the BOM character from the `StringIO` instance?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it not possible to remove the BOM before creating the StringIO instance or creating another one based on a UTF-8 string without BOM? All released StringIO versions don't support BOM handling.

Comment: The problem is that (since Ruby 2.4) BOM is a property of _files_, not an encoding. If you already have an encoded string, there is no such thing as BOM because the characters have already been properly read according to the BOM, and it is now unneeded. Since StringIO is backed by a string--not a file--it also does not understand BOM.

Answer (score 6):

Ruby 2.7 added the [`set_encoding_by_bom`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-i-set_encoding_by_bom) method to `IO`. This methods consumes the byte order mark and sets the encoding.

```
require 'csv'
require 'stringio'

CSV_READ_OPTIONS = { headers: true }.freeze

content = StringIO.new("\xEF\xBB\xBFid\n123")
content.set_encoding_by_bom

first_row = CSV.parse(content, CSV_READ_OPTIONS).first
first_row.headers.first.include?("\xEF\xBB\xBF")
#=> false
```

Answer (score 2):

Ruby doesn't like BOMs. It *only handles them when reading a file*, never anywhere else, and even then it only reads them so that it can get rid of them. If you want a BOM for your string, or a BOM when writing a file, you have to handle it manually.

There are probably gems for doing this, though it's easy to do yourself

```
if string[0...3] == "\xef\xbb\xbf"
  string = string[3..-1].force_encoding('UTF-8')
elsif string[0...2] == "\xff\xfe"
  string = string[2..-1].force_encoding('UTF-16LE')
# etc
```

Answer (score 2):

I found out that forcing encoding to utf8 on the StringIO `string` and removing the BOM to generate a new StringIO worked:

```
require 'csv'
CSV_READ_OPTIONS = { headers: true}.freeze
content = StringIO.new("\xEF\xBB\xBFid\n123")
csv_file = StringIO.new(content.string.force_encoding('utf-8').sub("\xEF\xBB\xBF", ''))
first_row = CSV.parse(csv_file, CSV_READ_OPTIONS).first

first_row.headers.first.include?("\xEF\xBB\xBF") # => false
```

The `encoding` option is no more needed. It may not be the best option memory-wise, but it works.